# Dynamic string array structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

I am new to C and I want to create a dynamic array to store strings. I wrote the code below for it but it didn't work. Array elements contain some ASCII chars instead of string.
I want `historyArray[0]` value to be `"foo"`. How can I do that?

```
typedef struct {
    char *historyCommand;
    int usedSize;
    int maximumSize;
} HistoryArray;

void CreateHistoryArray(HistoryArray *HistoryArray) {
    HistoryArray->historyCommand = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LEN);
    HistoryArray->usedSize = 0;
    HistoryArray->maximumSize = INITIAL_SIZE;
}

void ExpandHistoryArray(HistoryArray *HistoryArray, int newSize) {
    int *newArray = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * newSize);
    memcpy(newArray, HistoryArray->historyCommand, sizeof(char) * HistoryArray->maximumSize);
    free(HistoryArray->historyCommand);
    HistoryArray->historyCommand = newArray;
    HistoryArray->maximumSize = newSize;
}

void AddHistoryValue(HistoryArray *HistoryArray, char historyCommand[]) {
    strcpy(HistoryArray->historyCommand[HistoryArray->usedSize], historyCommand);

    HistoryArray->usedSize++;

    if (HistoryArray->usedSize == HistoryArray->maximumSize) {
        ExpandHistoryArray(HistoryArray, HistoryArray->maximumSize * 2);
    }
}

void freeHistoryArray(HistoryArray *a) {
    free(a->historyCommand);
    a->historyCommand = NULL;
    a->usedSize = 0;
    a->maximumSize = 2;
}


HistoryArray historyArray;
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. How and which functions are you calling? "I want historyArray[0] value is "foo". That doesn't make sense. `historyArray[0]` is not a `char` array. Please be more precise in your description. And please format your code with proper indentation to make it readable.

Comment: `char *HistoryArray` is not an array of strings, it's an array of characters, which is just a single string.

Comment: `BTW`, `malloc + memcpy + free` is the same as `realloc`.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Isn't the compiler warning you about a wrong argument type in the `strcpy()` line?

Comment: @Bamar no it's not an array. It's a char pointer

Comment: @Fredrik But since he initializes it with `malloc`, it's a pointer to the array of characters that was allocated.

Comment: @Bamar no it's a char pointer to the begining of the memory allocated with malloc. It's not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code.

1. `char *historyCommand` is a pointer to a single string, not an array of strings. For a pointer to an array of strings you should use `char **historyCommand`.
2. You don't need to allocate the space for the individual strings when you create the `HistoryArray`. You can allocate the proper amount of space each time you add to the array, using the length of the string you're adding.
3. You should use `realloc()` instead of calling `malloc()`, `memcpy()`, and `free()`. This has the benefit that sometimes it can simply expand the memory it already allocated, so no copying will be needed.
4. When you're freeing the `HistoryArray`, you need to free all the strings. You shouldn't free `historyCommand`, because you set `maximumSize = 2`, and the other functions assume that this means there's room for 2 items there, which isn't true if you set `historyCommand` to `NULL`. So you should resize it to `maximumSize` to be consistent with the rest of the code.

Here's the new code:

```
typedef struct {
    char **historyCommand;
    int usedSize;
    int maximumSize;
} HistoryArray;

void CreateHistoryArray(HistoryArray *HistoryArray) {
    HistoryArray->historyCommand = malloc(INITIAL_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
    HistoryArray->usedSize = 0;
    HistoryArray->maximumSize = INITIAL_SIZE;
}

void ExpandHistoryArray(HistoryArray *HistoryArray, int newSize) {
    HistoryArray->historyCommand = realloc(HistoryArray->historyCommand, newSize * sizeof(char *));
    HistoryArray->maximumSize = newSize;
}

void AddHistoryValue(HistoryArray *HistoryArray, char historyCommand[]) {
    historyCommand[HistoryArray->usedSize] = malloc(strlen(historyCommand) + 1);
    strcpy(HistoryArray->historyCommand[HistoryArray->usedSize], historyCommand);

    HistoryArray->usedSize++;

    if (HistoryArray->usedSize == HistoryArray->maximumSize) {
        ExpandHistoryArray(HistoryArray, HistoryArray->maximumSize * 2);
    }
}

void freeHistoryArray(HistoryArray *a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a->usedSize; i++) {
        free a->historyCommand[i];
    }
    a->usedSize = 0;
    a->maximumSize = 2;
    a->historyCommand = realloc(a->historyCommand, a->maximumSize * sizeof(char *));
}

HistoryArray historyArray;
```

Comment: The code from [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) gives me a warnings like `warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`. Try it [here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7aSL4jjZf8R) out.